# Selected Item of ComboBox is displayed wrong by using of DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datatemplate

I have a problem with the ComboBox. The items are displayed when the ComboBox is opened. When I select an item and the ComboBox is closing, the ComboBox displaying `Model.Person` instead of `Name, Vorname`.

1. How can I solve that?
2. How can I realize an auto suggestion?

I have a ComboBox with a DataTamplate.

```xml
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PersonenComboboxTemplate}"
 x:Name="Person1CheckboxName" Text="Choose Person" IsEditable="True"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Personenliste}"
 SelectionChanged="Person1CheckboxName_SelectionChanged" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="PersonenComboboxTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text=", "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Vorname}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I use the MVVM-Pattern. The Data Binding is implemented in the ViewModel.

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Personenliste
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<Person> persColl = 
                                              new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            List<Person> personen = 
                          databaseConnection.getAllPersonsRAW().ToList<Person>();
            // sort by Vorname and Nachname
            personen.Sort(new PersonComparer());
            foreach (Person p in personen)
            {
                persColl.Add(p);
            }
            return persColl;
        }
    }
```

A `Person` has a given name (`Vorname`) and a surname (`Name`). (generated by ADO.NET Entity Data Model)

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="dataModel", Name="Person")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Person : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory-Methode

    /// <summary>
    /// Erstellt ein neues Person-Objekt.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="personID">Anfangswert der Eigenschaft PersonID.</param>
    public static Person CreatePerson(global::System.Int64 personID)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.PersonID = personID;
        return person;
    }

    #endregion
    ...
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Name");
            _Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnNameChanged();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How is the Person class declared?

Comment: generated by ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override ToString() in Person class (or partial class) to return `Name + " " + Vorname`:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public override ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Vorname);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Since ToString() is not something that reacts to change notifications, as H.B. pointed out in the comments, you can use this second approach:

```
// In PersonPartial.cs
public partial class Person
{
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Vorname); }
    }

    partial void OnNameChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayText");
    }

    partial void OnVornameChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayText");
    }
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox ... DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" />
```

Comment: And `IsTextSearchEnabled="True"` solve the second problem. :-)

Comment: I'm with @H.B. it sounds like a resource scope issue w.r.t. `StaticTemplate`.

Comment: @H.B. Why is it a bad hack? The OP stated that he uses MVVM, which means that the Person class is a viewmodel, it's sole purpose is databinding for a view. So, it would be logical to override ToString to something meaningfull, and it also would circumvent the need to override the template for a control, which is what the OP needed.

Comment: @BorisB.: I would argue that overriding `ToString` to achieve something in the application logic is never a logical step in *any* case. Further if any of the properties changes the view will not be updated because it *is not even bound*, it just executed once a method which should not exist in the first place.

Comment: @H.B. I see your point about the lack of later change notification when using ToString, I've added an alternative answer. But I still don't agree that ToString is useless. :)  It was made for string representation of an object, and here it is being used for that purpose (representation, not "something in the application logic"), but you were right about the binding part.

Comment: @BorisB.: I never said it is useless but displaying `ToString` in the UI *is* application logic, i for one would only use it to make the debugger show some key properties of the object in question.